# SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = integer

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have defined my two entities classes where an Account table can have multiple contacts. The JPA class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class AccountEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * serialVersionUID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8875162570848460130L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer userId;
    
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
    @Column(name = "USER_UUID")
    private UUID userUuid;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "MIDDLE_NAME")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "DOB")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userAccountEntity")
    private List<ContactsEntity> userContactList;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACTS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "contact_entity_type")
public class BaseContactsEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CONTACTS_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer userContactId;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_TYPE")
    private String phoneType;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Integer userId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_UUID", referencedColumnName = "USER_UUID")
    private UserAccountEntity userAccountEntity;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACTS")
public class ContactsEntity extends BaseContactsEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2553316166097098867L;

}
```

The AccountEntity is for the Account table which can have more than one contacts. I created BaseContactsEntity and ContactsEntity classes where ContactsEntity can later add additional columns based on the client needs and BaseContactsEntity will always have the predefined capabilities. When I try to retrieve the Account Entity record using "findUserByUserName" JPA query it tries to fetch both Account and related Contacts object. This query fails and gives the following error:

```
SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

When I remove the BaseContactsEntity and remove the inherit annotations the query works fine and it fetches the required results but after adding the BaseContactsEntity I started seeing this error. Any leads to resolve this issue would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the join column definition.

Current:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_UUID", referencedColumnName = "USER_UUID")
```

Should be probably:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
```

Alternatively you can create a column USER_UUID in the CONTACTS table.

Comment: ```@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_UUID", referencedColumnName = "USER_UUID")
    private UserAccountEntity userAccountEntity;``` This code creates the column UUID in the Contacts table.

Comment: But apparently it will be created with type integer as the error shows. Better define all columns explicitly in the entity. To avoid such errors.